# Fill anomaly ofter joining paths in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, fill

I created this image building a gear tooth and then rotated it around the centre.  The path looks good until I try to fill it and as you can see I have an annoying join across teeth.

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to eliminate this??

**[image: fi]**

fill is brown, stroke is blue

Answer (score 1):

there is two possibilities:

1. your  path is an open path, so check your anchors and close what it could be opened.
2. the gear tooth that you rotate it may overlapped. The last gear tooth with the first one.

Comment: Thanks.  It was possibility 2!  I've fixed it up now :-)